# A meteor package for location reporting on the background upon request send using GCM and APN

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

The scenario: A meteor mobile app is required to report a user's location on request from server. The request arrives via GCM on Android and APN on iOS. When the request arrives the app may be on background or inactive altogether.

The main challenge - how the app answers the GCM without the user bothered. Bonus points if the client handler resides in javascript code, that does anything, not specifically location reporting.

I have this implemented in Cordova, using a plugin with native code. Was wondering if there is a similar solution on meteor (or at least how such solution would look like). It seems most packages that deal with GCM and APN focus on notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out meteor can add a cordova plugin as if it were a package

```
meteor add cordova:<plugin id>@https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/tarball/<commit>
```

So I can use my plugin (https://github.com/uriva/PushPlugin)